# degree, closeness, betweenness for each connected network

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph with several disconnected components. For example:

```
library(igraph)
g <- simplify(
  graph.compose(
    graph.ring(10), 
    graph.star(5, mode = "undirected")
  )
) + edge("7", "8")
```

[image]

I want to calculate closeness, betweenness, degree for each of these 3 connected networks. Till now I have managed to separate the networks but don't know how to proceed further.
This is the code I wrote:

```
x <- clusters(g)
dg <- decompose.graph(g) # returns a list of three graphs
plot(dg[[156]], vertex.label=NA)

x1 <- data.frame(x$membership)
x1 <- cbind(Row.Names = rownames(x1), x1)
x1<- data.frame(x1)
rownames(x1) <- NULL
names(x1) <- c("email","membership")

x2 <- data.frame(x$csize)
x2 <- cbind(Row.Names = rownames(x2), x2)
x2 <- data.frame(x2)
rownames(x2) <- NULL
names(x2) <- c("membership","number_of_connections")
x2$membership <- as.numeric(x2$membership)

network <- merge(x1, x2, by = "membership")
```

This is my output:

[image]

I am trying to calculate 3 different columns: degree, closeness, betweenness for each email.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dg is your list of networks, then you can use lapply to calculate the betweenness centrality of each network.

```
dg_bet<-lapply(dg,betweenness)
```

Then map_df from the purrr package to convert the list to a dataframe.

```
dg_bet <- map_df(dg_bet, ~as.data.frame(.x), .id="id")
```

Which gives you

```
       id  .x
   1   1 6.0
   2   1 1.5
   3   1 0.5
   4   1 0.5
   5   1 0.5
   6   1 0.0
   7   1 1.0
   8   2 0.0
   9   2 0.0
   10  3 0.0
```

You could apply this approach to calculating closeness and degree then use cbind to join these up to your main dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I add another column "email" for each row in dg_bet? Please note that the example I have given here is a toy example and in my actual data, "email" column is not a sequence of numbers but some real email ids

Answer (score 2):

You can just compute all of those things.

```
B = rep(0, vcount(g))
for(i in 1:3) { B[x$membership==i] = betweenness(dg[[i]]) }
C = rep(0, vcount(g))
for(i in 1:3) { C[x$membership==i] = closeness(dg[[i]]) }

Nodes = data.frame(membership = x$membership, 
        email = 1:10,
        connections = x$csize[x$membership],
        degree = degree(g),
        closeness = C,
        betweenness = B)
Nodes
   membership email connections degree  closeness betweenness
1           1     1           7      5 0.14285714         6.0
2           1     2           7      5 0.14285714         1.5
3           1     3           7      3 0.11111111         0.5
4           1     4           7      3 0.11111111         0.5
5           1     5           7      3 0.11111111         0.5
6           1     6           7      1 0.08333333         0.0
7           2     7           2      1 1.00000000         0.0
8           2     8           2      1 1.00000000         0.0
9           3     9           1      0        NaN         0.0
10          1    10           7      4 0.11111111         1.0
```

Comment: Thanks @G5W. This above method is working for small data but my dataset is Huge. It is taking a lot of time to compute.